# Ssrs Report Mdx Query Is Not Returning The Value While It Getting Result In Ssms

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

When executing the below `mdx` query in `ssms` it returned 3 rows.But the same
query in `ssrs` displays an error.

> The ALLMEMBERS function expects a hierarchy expression for the
>   argument.A member expression was used.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
    [RMS].[Risk Organisational sector].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
    [RMS].[Risk Organisational sector].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
    [RMS].[Risk Organisational sector].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterValue]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterLevel]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[RMS].[Risk Organisational sector].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [Risk Assigned Scoring Scheme].[Assigned Scoring Scheme Name].[All]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {
        [Risk Assessment Type].[Current or Forecast Assessment].&[Current]
      } ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        {
          [Risk].[Risk Status].&[Active]
         ,[Risk].[Risk Status].&[Unapproved]
        } ON COLUMNS
      FROM [Business - Risk]
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Use profiler to see exactly what MDX is being executed by your SSRS report.   Verify that it is submitting to the same SSAS Database as you are testing on SSMS.

Comment: Have you tried using the function `.MEMBERS` instead?

Comment: Try having an explicit set by encloising `[RMS].[Risk Organisational sector].ALLMEMBERS` in curly braces. Have this - `{[RMS].[Risk Organisational sector].ALLMEMBERS}` in MDX

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: Please post an answer and mark it as resolved if you were able to get around the issue. Else please let know of any further roadblock.